# My excel keep on crashing when I perform the code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Sub NewRecord() to create new record and a Sub CB_No_Change() to recall existing record by number to be displayed on the user form. For Sub NewRecord(), I write the code so that some default values are put into the excel sheet in the next empty row then this new record is recalled by Sub CB_No_Change() to be displayed on the user form and can be edited. The Sub CB_No_Change() is working fine on its own, but the Sub NewRecord() usually crashes when being run (the excel application does not respond and automatically reboots). I suspect there may be a loop between this 2 subs? Any ideas?

```
Private Sub NewRecord()

    Dim LastRow As Integer

    Dim emptyRow As Integer

    LastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("$A:$A"))

    emptyRow = LastRow + 1

    Cells(emptyRow, 1) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 2) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 3) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 4) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 5) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 6) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 7) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 8) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 9) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 10) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 11) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 12) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 13) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 14) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 15) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 16) = "xxx"
    Cells(emptyRow, 17) = "xxx"

    Me.CB_No = LastRow
    Me.TB_RecdDate.SetFocus
End sub

Private Sub CB_No_Change()

    Dim FindNo As String
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim TrgtNo As Range

    If Me.CB_No <> "" Then
        FindNo = Me.CB_No.Value
        Set TrgtNo = Worksheets("One").Range("$A:$A").Find(FindNo, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not TrgtNo Is Nothing Then
            r = Worksheets("One").Range("$A:$A").Find(FindNo, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, Lookat:=xlWhole).Row

            CB = Cells(r, 1)
            TB = Cells(r, 2)
            Me.TB = Format(Me.TB, "yyyy-mm-dd")
            TB = Cells(r, 3)
            Me.TB = Format(Me.TB, "yyyy-mm-dd")
            TB = Cells(r, 4)
            TB = Cells(r, 5)
            TB = Cells(r, 6)
            TB = Cells(r, 7)
            CB = Cells(r, 8)
            CB = Cells(r, 9)
            CB = Cells(r, 10)
            TB = Cells(r, 11)
            TB = Cells(r, 12)
            TB = Cells(r, 13)
            CB = Cells(r, 14)
            CB = Cells(r, 15)
            CB = Cells(r, 16)
            TB = Cells(r, 17)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `LastRow ` and `emptyRow ` need to be declared as `Long`

Comment: Do your variables ever get larger than 32,767? if so, use `Long` instead of `Integer`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Best way to get the last row used in a column is: `LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: What does "crashing" mean? Does it show an error message (then include the message in your question) or does it just force close Excel (then it is not an issue in your code but an error/bug in Excel itself) • Update your Excel to the most recent version.

Comment: Crashing means that the excel application stops responding and reboots

Comment: It is still crashing after amend to `LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Regarding the "loop between this 2 subs": I can't see how these subs call each other. In theory, an indirect method is possible (through event handlers), if so, please indicate it.

Comment: If Excel crashes, please Compile the project before running any part of it. In VB Editor go to the Debug menu, and choose Compile. See if there is any compilation error anywhere in your code. If so, fix it. After that see if it still crashes.

Comment: @z32a7ul As in the first Sub one line `Me.CB_No=LastRow`, will it trigger the Sub CB_NO_Change()? And no error found in debug too.

Comment: @TaylorJansen It can trigger if CB_No is a CommandButton and CB_NO_Change its event handler. But I see no link in the other direction.

Comment: What version of Excel do you use? Is it updated?

Comment: @z32a7ul It is Office 365 version 1908

Comment: I think the next step should be to replace unqualified references. `Range("$A:$A")` refers to the ActiveSheet. Try to replace them with something like `Me.Range("$A:$A")` or `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A:$A")`. The same applies to `Cells`.

Comment: @z32a7ul I did what you suggested. Not helping :(  Still the same "Run Time Error -2147417848 (80010108)"  Any idea?

Comment: @TaylorJansen What do you mean by "Still the same"? Until this you wrote that the symptom is "the excel application stops responding and reboots". Getting an error message is something different. Please describe on which line you get it. If it comes up as a dialog box, then click Debug, then in the Immediate Window write `? Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source, Err.LastDllError`, hit Enter, and tell us what you got.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, it looks like you are trying to get the row number of the last row in column A, so you can get the row number of the first empty row adding +1 to `LastRow`.

You are using `CountA`, a function that just counts non-empty cells in a range.

> **[WorksheetFunction.CountA method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.counta)**

This will work **only** if all your data is continuous. But if your data is like this:

[image]

You can see this with an easy code applied to data in the image:

```
Sub test()

Dim LastRowWithCountA As Long
Dim LastRowNormal As Long

LastRowWithCountA = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
LastRowNormal = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Debug.Print "COUNTA: " & LastRowWithCountA & " VS " & "NORMAL:" & LastRowNormal

End Sub
```

It will return `COUNTA: 15 VS NORMAL:19`.

So the best option to get the last non empty row in a column is `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

About your error, replace`Integers` with `Long`. Integers got a lower limit. I recommend you to read all data types admited.

> **[Data type summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary)**

Comment: Declaring it as Integer cannot cause it crash.

Comment: @z32a7ul Integer admits values between -32,768 to 32,767. If last used row is 40.000, you can't save that value into an Integer variable, causing Excel to crash, with an overflow error.

Comment: No it, does not crash. Try to run the following: `Public Sub DoesItCrash(): Dim intTest As Integer: intTest = 32767: intTest = intTest + 1: End Sub` It will show a dialog box: Run-time error 6: Overflow. And you can click Debug or End. The OP wrote that Excel crashed (gave a detailed description of the symptom )which is very commendable): "does not respond and automatically reboots"). That's different.

Comment: @z32a7ul OP posted *Crashing means that the excel application stops responding and reboots* a day ago. My answer is 2 days ago. Original question was not so detailed at all. Anyways, I see your point in what you mean by crashing.